# Java program stalls then stops when it reaches a loop

Tags: java, loops

I have a program (written in Java) that when it reaches a for or a while loop, it stalls for about 2 seconds then stops completely. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class numberCruncher
{
   public static int number,guess,x;
   public static void main(String[] argv)
   {  
      number=enterIntGUI("Enter a number for the\ncomputer to crack\n(5 digits maximum):"); 
      System.out.print("1");
      test();
   }
   public static void test()
   {  
      boolean correct = false;
      System.out.print("2");
      //while(correct=false)
      for(x=0;x>999999999;x++)
      {
         //x++;
         System.out.print("3");
         guess=cleanUsage.random(0,99999);
         System.out.print("4");
         System.out.println(" "+guess);
         if (guess==number)
         {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Correct number guessed in "+x+" tries");
            //correct = true;
         }
      }
   }
   public static int enterIntGUI(String prompt)
   {
      String tempString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
      int temp = Integer.parseInt(tempString);
      return temp;
   }
}
```

You can see that I have comments for the while loop stuff. Also, I have put in 4 println statements where I thought it would be getting stuck, and it printed 1 and 2, but not 3. Here is the portion of my cleanUsage class that contains the random number generator:

```
public static int random(int min, int max)
    {
        int range = max - min + 1;
        int number = (int) (range * Math.random() + min);
        return number;
    }
```

I have asked some other people and they could not figure it out. If you could help me out, that would be great.

Comment: `for(x=0;x>999999999;x++)` will never run as it doesn't satisfies the condition `x>999999999`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't print `3` or `4` because the condition `x>999999999` is initially `false` so that `for` loop is never entered. I assume you meant `<`.

Also note that you can use `break` rather than `correct = true` to exit a loop.

Comment: I did mean that for the for loop, but the while loop should have worked anyway, right?

Comment: No, because you should use `==` to test equality. `=` is assignment .

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class numberCruncher
{
   public static int number,guess,x;
   public static void main(String[] argv)
{  
  number=enterIntGUI("Enter a number for the\ncomputer to crack\n(5 digits maximum):"); 
  System.out.print("1");
  test();
}
public static void test()
{  
   boolean correct = false;
   System.out.print("2");
   //while(correct==false)  // equality test, not assignment
   for(x=0;x<999999999;x++) //2nd argument is continue while false
   {
      //x++;
      System.out.print("3");
      guess=cleanUsage.random(0,99999);
      System.out.print("4");
      System.out.println(" "+guess);
      if (guess==number)
      {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Correct number guessed in "+x+" tries");
        //correct = true;
      }
   }
}
public static int enterIntGUI(String prompt)
   {
    String tempString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(tempString);
    return temp;
   }
}
```